# Qt-Using signals and slots with different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I'm still struggling to get this working as I expect.

I have a Qt project which I would like to update depending on signal states from different threads. My main GUI thread should start a worker thread running on the press of a start button.

The worker thread should then execute a function which continuously polls variables belonging to another class which are being updated by even a different thread (I am using portaudio libraries). It should then fire a signal (sendNewSig) which is connected to a slot (DrawData) in my GUI class.

The problem is the program crashes when I press my start button. I believe that I am missing some vital steps to start executing the worker thread. By calling updater->PollSignal() like this when the start button is clicked, I am expecting it to run in a new thread but perhaps not. I have shown parts of the code below which hopefully is enough to get my idea across.

Many thanks in advance for any help

In GUIApp.cpp

```
AudioGuiApplication::AudioGuiApplication(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    //......  other stuff

    thread = new QThread(this);
    updater = new GUIUpdater(&audio_processor);
    updater->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(updater, SIGNAL(sendNewSig(string)), this, SLOT(DrawData(string)));

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(destroyed()), updater, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    actionText->setPlainText("Press Start to begin ");
}

void AudioGuiApplication::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    updater->PollSignal();
}
```

In GUIUpdater.cpp`

```
void GUIUpdater::PollSignal() 
{ 
    string str;

    while (!ap->IsNewDataFound() )
    {
        emit sendNewSig(str);
        ap->SetNewSigFound(false);
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `PollSignal` function from the main/gui thread directly.

I think the easiest way to execute it in the desired thread is to employ the Signal & Slot mechanism with a single-shot `QTimer` set at no delay (`0` stands for 0 milliseconds):

```
void AudioGuiApplication::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(0, updater, &GUIUpdater::PollSignal);
}
```

By the way: you should consider moving to the ["new" `connect` syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) that doesn't rely on macros and allows compile-time type validation instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that . The GUI is not being updated like I expected however. As my signal is connected to my slot like this :   connect(updater, SIGNAL(sendNewSig(string)), this, SLOT(DrawData(string)));   When I do emit sendNewSig(str) in my poll function, shouldn't this call The DrawData function of my GUI class with str as the parameter? DrawData is not a slot tho, just a normal member function

Comment: `DrawData` *must* be a slot for the old-style `connect` syntax. Also, you need to register `string` in the Qt's reflection mechanisms: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType Otherwise the Auto/QueuedConnection (which it is in your case) won't work. I assumed this wasn't the problem, because the question wasn't about it :)

Comment: register string in the reflection mechanisms? I'm not sure I understand. How and where would I do this? Thanks

Comment: You actually need to do it once (i.e. in your main function or in the constructor of `AudioGuiApplication`. Otherwise your signals and slots connected used the old mechanism (with macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`) that require queueing of the parameters won't know how to do so. How: I linked `qRegisterMetaType`. You'd basically call `qRegisterMetaType<string>("string")`, just be sure that the actual name you use is exactly the same as the function parameter in `connect` (i.e. don't mix `std::string` and `string`). Or, just go the easier way and use the new connect.

Comment: Actually, the docs suggest that you use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` instead: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE The effect is going to be more or less the same, although for this macro the documentation states clearly that you need `qRegisterMetaType` anyway:  *Note that if you intend to use the type in queued signal and slot connections or in QObject's property system, you also have to call qRegisterMetaType() since the names are resolved at runtime.*

Comment: I'm not having any success here still )  The DrawData slot / function is just not being called no matter what. How would I connect the signal and slot using the new connect? I am actually using std::string

Comment: Try `connect(updater, &GUIUpdater::sendNewSig, this, &AudioGuiApplication::DrawData);`

Comment: Yes I've tried exactly that already but no joy. What about the string parameter in that case?

Comment: You're passing pointers to member functions, unless you overloaded the signal/slot there's no need to do anything more. Perhaps at this point you should prepare a MVCE and post a new question, though. What I suggested *should* work, and just going by the discussion in comments I have no clue why it doesn't.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will look into it more. Why don't I have to take care about the run() in thread tho? Is updater->moveToThread(thread) simply enough? I'm completely new to Qt , so still learning

Comment: Now that you mention it, you need to call `start()` on the thread instance (preferably in the constructor of the main GUI object). You shouldn't inherit and override `run()` or call it directly.

Comment: @Engineer999 try this: https://github.com/KrzaQ/so-44376979 Hopefully you'll find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter if the QThread gets allocated dynamically or not. In my code I am doing : thread = new QThread(this) inside my main GUI class. In your example and many other i've seen, the thread is a class member not as a pointer

Comment: It should not,.